# Cannot access database instances with id=pk

Tags: django-models, django-views

Here is my views.py file. I input the required fields through form like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import nekor_Table
from .forms import user_form

def home(request):
    user_form_obj = user_form()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = user_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            form = user_form_obj()
            
    context = {'user_form_obj': user_form_obj}
    return render(request, 'polls/home.html', context )


def nav(request):
    
    return render(request, 'navbar.html')

def display(request, pk):
    display_table_obj = nekor_Table.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'display_table_obj': display_table_obj}
    return render(request, 'polls/display_page.html', context)
```

i have two tables and when i try to get individual instance with id=pk, and running http://127.0.0.1:8000/display/1/ in my browser it gives me: nekor_Table matching query does not exist, error. what am i missing here? this was working just fine in my previous project but doesnt work in this one.

here is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('index/', views.home, name='home'),
    path('navbar/', views.nav, name='navbar'),
    path('display/<int:pk>/', views.display, name='display')

]
```

and here is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class nekor_Table(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    deity = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=False)
    teachers = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    architecture = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Code looks fine. I would suggest to check if your database for real contains a `nekor_Table` entry with corresponding `pk=1`. Open `python manage.py shell`, `from yourapp.models import nekor_Table` and then check for the same query with: `nekor_Table.objects.get(pk=1)`. Because I think it does not exist. And then it is correct that this error occurs. You can avoid it with `nekor_Table.objects.get_or_404(pk=1)` in your view.

Comment: i had to delete the database and run migrations again, coz it still had the database entries from previous code. thanks for your input.